# search for last created text file and importe it to Sql using C#

Tags: c#

I have list of Text file, i need C# tools to find the last created file and load it to SQL
i have job work twice in a day one at 05:15AM & 12:15AM and generate two Text file (genset_20090103_1212.TXT), I need to get last created one and append its data to sql

Comment: why not check the created timestamp of file and pick the right one?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using linq

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory")

var lastcreatedfile = (from c in directory.GetFiles()
             orderby c.CreationTime descending
             select c).First();

 string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\MyDirectory"+lastcreatedfile.FullName+".txt");
```

insert the content text  to your sql

Comment: @user1371482 look at this example  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
FileInfo file1Info = new FileInfo("File1.txt");
        FileInfo file2Info = new FileInfo("File2.txt");
        if (file1Info.LastWriteTime < file2Info.LastWriteTime)
        {
            //Insert File2.txt in your Database
        }
```